# Python - Split PDF based on list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

I'm trying to split a PDF into separate PDF files into new files based on a list. Code as follows:

```
import sys
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

def splitByStudent(file, group):
    inputPdf = PdfFileReader(open(file,"rb"))
    output = PdfFileWriter()
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(file))
    os.chdir(path)
    numpages = int(inputPdf.numPages/len(group))
    for s in group:
        startpage = group.index(s) * numpages
        endpage = startpage + numpages
        newfile = s + ".pdf"
        for i in range(startpage, endpage):
            output.addPage(inputPdf.getPage(i))
            with open(newfile, "wb") as outputStream:
                output.write(outputStream)





BIASL1 = ["Student One", "Student Two"]

file = "filename.pdf"

splitByStudent(file, BIASL1)
```

The PDF "filename" has 16 pages and the name of the first file produced is "Student One.pdf", which should have the correct 8 pages. "Student Two.pdf", however contains all 16 pages of the original. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The line `output = PdfFileWriter()` should be inside the for loop:

```
def splitByStudent(file, group):
    inputPdf = PdfFileReader(open(file,"rb"))
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(file))
    os.chdir(path)
    numpages = int(inputPdf.numPages/len(group))
    for s in group:
        output = PdfFileWriter()
        startpage = group.index(s) * numpages
        endpage = startpage + numpages
        newfile = s + ".pdf"
        for i in range(startpage, endpage):
            output.addPage(inputPdf.getPage(i))
            with open(newfile, "wb") as outputStream:
                output.write(outputStream)
```